# Settings File as Dictionary with Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary, settings

This is a three part question.

**One:** Would using a

```
Dictionary<String,Object>
```

be a good way of saving data where it would be

```
Dictionary<Key,Value>
```

as the basis?

**Two:** What would be a better way without using app.settings or xml?

**Three:** How would you serialize this(Or the better solution) into a binary format that is compact and serializes quickly?

---

Xml is very verbose and I was looking for binary due to it's size.
Also, if I used Dictionary, it would have been easy to make a settings class with simply

```
GetValue(Key) and SetValue(Key,Obj)
or object.SetValue(Settings,Key) using extensions.
```

I am making my application open for plugins so I wanted a uniform spec for settings that all applications use.

Rolling my own class using Dictionary as the basis made sense if I could serialize it into a file.

Comment: Why not just use app.settings? What's wrong with it?

Comment: xml is very verbose and I was looking for binary due to it's size.
Also, if I used Dictionary, it would have been easy to make a settings class with simply GetValue(Key) and SetValue(Key,Obj) or object.SetValue(Settings,Key) using extensions.

I am making my application open for plugins so I wanted a uniform spec for settings that all applications use.

Rolling my own class using Dictionary as the basis made sense if I could serialize it into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). This would solve all three of your problems. I looked at it last week, and replaced my entire xml-based messaging infrastructure in just a couple of days. Marc Gravell is a frequent contributor on here, and he was very prompt and helpful in his replies to my queries.

Comment: How would I use this for settings? Can it serialize a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, you can serialize a dictionary. In fact, I did this in my solution.

For "Settings" I take it you mean that you want to store some values and restore them later, as in save/load?

This would be easy. You'd take your object that you want to save, generate a serialized representation, and save that. Then deserialize it when you like.

The only issue is that protobufs saves stuff in a very compact binary form, so you wont be able to visually recognize that the stuff is saved correctly. But it will still work.

Comment: Does it support Generics in that a dictionary<string,object> would still serialize? Since this is a wrapper around a dictionary, would protobuf-net serialize the dictionary instance inside the settings class?

Basically I am implimenting a key-value system in the dictionary where both the key and the value need to be serialized.

sorry if I am sounding a bit noobish, I am still learning programming.

Comment: I think there's an issue around serializing object, because it doesn't quite know how to do it. That's where I had to make some small changes to my structure. Marc says V2, which is out sometime soon, will address this. BTW, there's a stackoverflow question about this somewhere, but I forget what it was. But the question specifically has an example where someone tries to serialize object, and Marc came up with a solution.

Comment: @Carlos Sorry, but if you only want to directly serialize a "Settings" object, which inherits from Dictionary<string,string>, I don't see how this is possible without a wrapper / container object with protobuf-net.

Comment: @kitsune: What seems to be the issue? In my solution, I have a message class containing a dictionary, and there are appropriate attributes on both the class and the member. Also, since the message is inherited from a parent, the parent class also has an attribute specifying the child as being protobuffable. Apart from that, it just seems to work. Perhaps this is what you're missing?